# Why can’t I get references to work in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I’ve tried to reference other documents but I can’t get `ref` to work. It doesn’t even work inside the same document!

Here’s my example:

```
:ref:'my-reference-label'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of googling and finally copy-pasting some Sphinx markup that works, I discovered that it’s all down to a typo. I was writing this:

```
:ref:'my-reference-label'
```

When I should’ve been writing:

```
:ref:`my-reference-label`
```

Yes that’s a backtick right there. On the screen it looks so much like a single quotation mark that if you are rushing through the Sphinx documentation so you can actually start getting some work done, you might miss this tiny fact.

Oh and also the Sphinx documentation does not mention the word ‘backtick’, not even once. So if you don’t spot this on your own, well, too bad.

Can I have three hours of my life back, please?